# How to pass a value to TypeFilter C#

Tags: c#, api, .net-6.0

I am trying to allow and disallow access to a method in a controller. For this I added the **AuthorizationFilter** class, the problem I have is that I cannot pass a value to that class from the method before it is executed.

```
public class AuthorizationFilter : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public AuthorizationFilter()
    {

    }

    void IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            {
                string token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) && token.Contains("Bearer"))
                {
                    //validate IdRol with value into System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal

                }
                else
                    context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
            else
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exc);
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

The class that should receive a value of type **System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal** is **AuthorizationFilter**. In it I must receive the claims to identify whether or not the user has access to the method.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ClientesController : ControllerBase
{

    [TypeFilter(typeof(AuthorizationFilter))]//The claims inside this.User are what I must pass to the AuthorizationFilter class before execute the method
    [HttpGet(Name = nameof(GetClients))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetClients([FromQuery] ClientsSearch filter)
    {
        //The claims inside this.User are what I must pass to the AuthorizationFilter class before execute the method
        //System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal user = this.User;

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Please can you help me solve the problem I have, thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean [AuthorizationFilterContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.authorizationfiltercontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0).[HttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0).[User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.user?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httpcontext-user)?

Comment: @ErikPhilips If that's what I mean, to pass the claims to AuthorizationFilter, but I can't do it or I don't understand how to get the value. Thank you

Comment: They are already passed as part of the AuthorizationFilterContext.  You access them via `context.HttpContext.User`.. very similar to how you are currently accessing `context.HttpContext.Request`.